# ¿Cómo limitar registros específicos en una consulta de SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla con la siguiente estructura: `idProducto` `NombreP` `Precio` `Cantidad`.

No quiero tomar en cuenta algunos registros de `NombreP`, podría usar la siguiente consulta para filtrar lo que necesito:

```sql
select NombreP Precio Cantidad from VProductos
where NombreP in ('Tv','PC','Telefono'....)
```

No quiero usar `in` porque son demasiados registros para filtrar, y quería saber si puedo excluir algunos registros mediante un código.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con 'excluir algunos registros mediante un código'? ¿Quieres realizar la consulta fuera de SQL? ¿Estás excluyendo o incluyendo de la lista? Considera detallar más tu pregunta a fin que sea más sencillo revisarla.

Comment: Si quieres excluir elementos en vez de incluir , puedes usar `not in`

Comment: @RicVillalba Gracias me funciono

Comment: A modo de recomendación, recuerda generar preguntas con un grado de detalle, que ayuden a la comunidad a querer participar y a entender tu problema. La pregunta es muy general y da lugar a ambigüedades.